# Inserting MS Access data into Excel as new rows below existing data

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel

I need to import rows from an MS Access table into Excel. The VBA macro below does just that.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\test_db.mdb;DefaultDir=C:\Documents and Setting" _
        ), Array( _
        "s\Administrator\My Documents;DriverId=25;FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;" _
        )), Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.name, Table1.id, Table1.var1, Table1.var2" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\test_db`.Table1 Table1" _
        )
        .Name = "Query from MS Access Database"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertEntireRows
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

MS Access table1

```
name    id    var1    var2
joe     1     23      34
```

When I run the macro once, I get in Excel

```
name    id    var1    var2
joe     1     23      34
```

When I run the macro again, I get in Excel

```
name    id    var1    var2    name    id    var1    var2
joe     1     23      34      joe     1     23      34
```

instead of

```
name    id    var1    var2
joe     1     23      34
name    id    var1    var2
joe     1     23      34
```

Do you know what I should change in order to import MS Access rows into Excel as new rows of data below existing data?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
)), Destination:=Range("A1"))
```

to say something different. Perhaps

```
)), Destination:= Range("A65536").End(xlUp).offset(1,0)
```

You may need to do a bit more than just this depending on how you are importing the data.

Comment: would this only allow to insert one row at a time? i ask because i see an offset of 1 -- if so, that would be an issue, because sometimes i may need to insert an unknown number of rows

Comment: No, this takes the first cell with data above A65536 - presumably the last row of imported data - and moves one row below it.

Answer (score 0):

Enderland's answer worked great for me within a querytable where I am importing a month of text files into excel and appending them on to the end of each other.  part of the code is shown below.  the second sheet of the target workbook has the dates=filenames in it. I now realize I could ask the user for the month and year and generate the file names withing the loop. All are 31 except June, April, Sept, Nov =30 & Feb = 28/29. I will do that.

Dim sDate As String
Dim sDataPath As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim mMax As Integer
Dim Label_F_Name As String
Dim F_name As String

sDataPath = Worksheets("D&L").Cells(1, "G").Value ' values located in 2nd sheet of workbook
mMax = Worksheets("D&L").Cells(1, "D").Value  'values located in 2nd sheet of workbook

For i = 1 To mMax
    sDate = "A_" + CStr(Worksheets("D&L").Cells(1 + i, "A").Value) + ".csv" ' looping through list of dates in sheet

'Label the data column with file name so one can validate the data is from the correct file
    Label_F_Name = sDate + "........................."
    F_name = sDataPath + sDate
    Range("'D&L'!D5") = F_name

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" + F_name, Destination:=Range("H1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(4, 0)) ' offset for existing header
    .Name = Label_F_Name
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertEntireRows ' appends data to end of previous
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = False
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Next i